# accordion menu list in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get show and hide menu in javascript only. Below code I have so far. For some reason its not working.

Can anyone help me?

```
var menuHtm = '<ul id="demo-nav">'
    +'<li><strong>Demo Links</strong></li>'
    +'<li class="dropdown"><a href="../home/page1.html'+ext+'">Main Menu 1</a>'
    +'<ul style="display : none;text-decoration:none;">'
    +'<li><a href="../home/page2.html'+ext+'">Sub menu 1</a></li>'
    +'<li><a href="../home/page3.html'+ext+'">Sub menu 2</a></li>'
    +'</ul></li>'
    +'<li class="dropdown"><a href="../home/page4.html'+ext+'">Main Menu 2</a>'
    +'<ul style="display : none;text-decoration:none;">'
    +'<li><a href="../home/page5.html'+ext+'">Sub menu 1</a></li>'
    +'<li><a href="../home/page6.html'+ext+'">Sub menu 2</a></li>'
    +'</ul></li>'
    +'<li><a class="blue close" style="text-decoration:none; line-height:20px; cursor:pointer;">[x] close</a></li>'
    +'</ul>';

$('li.dropdown').click(function() {
    $('li.dropdown').not(this).find('ul').hide();
    $(this).find('ul').toggle();
});

$('#wrapper').append(menuHtm);
```

Comment: You should correct your html, clicking on `li.dropdown` will also redirect immediately to `../home/index.html`.

Comment: @ xxxmatko: changed links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add event handler after appending html. Change those statments with thier place. It should look like:

```
$('#wrapper').append(menuHtm); 
$('li.dropdown').click(function() {
       $('li.dropdown').not(this).find('ul').hide();
       $(this).find('ul').toggle();
    });
```

Comment: @ Lazarev Alexandr: can you please suggest how should I do that? I don't know about that.

Comment: yeah. its working now. But if I click on *Main menu 1/Main menu 2* then sub menus gone in fraction of second. If I remove anchor tag of *Main menu* then its showing sub menus. Why this so? If I want link on Main Menu also then how should I get that? Can you please tell me?

Comment: What do you mean by "sub menus gone in fraction of second. "? Do you mean that you are ridericting to new page?

Answer (score 2):

Please add `click()` event listener after adding your menu to `$('#wrapper')` like follows:

```
$('#wrapper').append(menuHtm);

$('li.dropdown').click(function() {
       $('li.dropdown').not(this).find('ul').hide();
       $(this).find('ul').toggle();
});
```

Comment: its working for above. But if I click on *Main menu 1/Main menu 2* then sub menus gone in fraction of second. If I remove anchor tag of *Main menu* then its showing sub menus. Why this so? If I want link on *Main Menu* also then how should I get that? Can you please tell me?

Comment: As I told you in comment to your post, inside your `li` you have `a` element with `href` set, which cause redirect when you click on it.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote your example:

```js
$(function() {
    var ext = "???";
    $("#wrapper").append(
     '<ul id="demo-nav">'
            + '<li><strong>Demo Links</strong></li>'
            + '<li>'
                + '<a class="dropdown" href="#">Main Menu 1</a>'
                + '<ul>'
                    + '<li><a href="../home/page2.html'+ext+'">Sub menu 1</a></li>'
                    + '<li><a href="../home/page3.html'+ext+'">Sub menu 2</a></li>'
                + '</ul>'
            + '</li>'
            + '<li>'
                + '<a class="dropdown" href="#">Main Menu 2</a>'
                + '<ul>'
                    + '<li><a href="../home/page5.html'+ext+'">Sub menu 1</a></li>'
                    + '<li><a href="../home/page6.html'+ext+'">Sub menu 2</a></li>'
                + '</ul>'
            + '</li>'
            + '<li>'
                + '<a href="#" class="blue close">[x] close</a>'
            + '</li>'
     +'</ul>');
    $("a.dropdown + ul").hide(0);
    $("a.dropdown").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
     $("a.dropdown").not(this).siblings("ul").hide(0);
     $(this).siblings("ul").toggle();
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```